# cancel interval when app goes on background

Tags: ionic-framework, setinterval

I new with app and angular.

My app use an interval to refresh the scope with a get request to the server. I want that interval to be cancel when the app goes to background.

I saw on other post '$onunload=function()' but i'm not sure if it is good or how to use it... I try: `$scope.$onunload=function(){
      // Make sure that the interval is destroyed when leaving app
    $scope.stopRefresh();
  };`

but it didn't work.

Note that stopRefresh() function work with leaving tab, it cancel interval...

in other hand, is there some way that I can restart the interval whan  coming back fro background?

here the full controler:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

main.controller("temperatureCtrl", ["$scope", "$rootScope", "$window", "$interval", "ArduinoService", function($scope, $rootScope, $window, $interval, service) {
  $rootScope.arduinoServerUrl = '';
  $rootScope.arduinoServerUrl = $window.localStorage['serverUrl'];

  var autoRefresh;
  $scope.channels = [];

  function onTabSelected() {
$rootScope.arduinoServerUrl = $window.localStorage['serverUrl'];
}

$scope.options = {
loop: false,
//effect: 'fade',
speed: 500,
}
$scope.data = {};
$scope.$watch('data.slider', function(nv, ov) {
$scope.slider = $scope.data.slider;
})

function startRefresh() {
autoRefresh = $interval(function() {
  updateAjax();
}, 5000);
}


function updateAjax() {
service.getChannels(function(err, result) { //get json data
  if (err) {
    return alert(err);
  }
  // puis les mets dans le scope
  $scope.channels = result.channels;
  })
};

$scope.init = function() { //on load page first get data
updateAjax();
//startRefresh()
}


$scope.stopRefresh = function() {
$interval.cancel(autoRefresh);
};

$scope.restartRefresh = function() {
startRefresh();
};

$scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', function() {
// Make sure that the interval is destroyed when leaving tab
$scope.stopRefresh();
});

$scope.$onunload=function(){
  // Make sure that the interval is destroyed when leaving app
$scope.stopRefresh();
};

$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
//star or restart interval scope update

$scope.restartRefresh();
});

$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
// Make sure that the interval is destroyed too
$scope.stopRefresh();
});

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing you need to make some singleton class  like in angularjs 'service' or 'factory'. Like I am doing in my code and then in that you just cancel the $inerval when resume event fire.

```
factory('BackgroundCheck', function($ionicPlatform){
    var service = {};
    var inBackground = false;

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {        
        document.addEventListener("resume", function(){inBackground = false;}, false);
        document.addEventListener("pause", function(){inBackground = true;}, false);
    });

    service.isActive = function(){
        return inBackground == false;
    }
    return service;    
})
```

I hope that will work for you.

Thanks...

Comment: it does a bit. I'm new to angular as well and never use factory... try to understand what is does... but you understand what I want to do.. :P. Can I simply inject $interval to the function and cancel it from there ? is the factory have to be call somewhere? I know I'm a real beginner... :p